# Pandas bug? applying lambda on multiple columns row.name has strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have the following code:

```
d = {'p': [1, 1], 'm': [1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.apply(lambda row: pandas.Series(meth(row.name)), axis=1)

def meth(i):
    return [2, 3]
```

During iteration and having a breakpoint at 'meth' return statement, the 'i' has the following values:

```
{int64} 0
{int} 0 !!!
{int} 1
```

so I have an additional iteration and a change of type, which is strange.
Python 3.6; Pandas 0.25.0, Pycharm
PyCharm 2019.2 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-192.5728.105, built on July 23, 2019

I have tried the code without 'pandas.Series', returning an only single integer, the row index is correct and its type is always {int64}.

What is wrong?

Comment: I believe the `apply` method has a test/optimization run before the actual loop. That's why you see two `0` values.

Comment: IIUC, on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6753) they address your concern about the "additional" iteration

Comment: This is [documented in the notes section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: Many thanks for the reference, my headache is better :)! This is however, a new variation of the theme as it is now context sensitive. Now I understand that 'this is expected' see github. Maybe I am wrong, but in the old days, programming did not mean that unexpected behavior was expected. :) At least, please, row.name need to be depreciated in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [notes section of the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html),

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.